# How to find the value of y for the following peaks

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=1)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x), "--", color="gray")
print(peaks)
plt.show()
```

**In the following program the peaks are calculated through scipy but when i print the values of peaks the only values that comes are along the x axis... Is there any way to print the values of peaks along x axis and y axis so that the information is complete in (x,y) coordinates..??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]
peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, height=1)
plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], "x")
plt.plot(np.zeros_like(x), "--", color="gray")
print( [(i,j) for i, j in zip(peaks, x[peaks] )] )  # To print x and corresponding peak at x
plt.show()
```